# Empty arrays not supported error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a workbook of sheets, one for each year, and need to get the average of all months that passed in the year of that sheet. The sheets are named by year and I named the formula: `MONTHS`.

```
=LET(year,VALUE(MID(CELL("filename"),SEARCH("]",CELL("filename"))+1,31)),IF(YEAR(TODAY())=year,MONTH(TODAY())-1,IF(year>YEAR(TODAY()),0,12)))
```

And use it to get an average :

[image]

It works most of the time, but when I do some things in other cells or sheets, it returns a *#CALC* error that empty arrays are not supported. When I recalculate the sheet it fixes itself, but it's very annoying to have to do that all the time. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Note that the TAKE function is not yet in the production version version of Excel. I assume your using the Insider version of Excel 365. Correct?

Comment: Can you post online a sample spreadsheet? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion based on years of APL use is that empty array support is essential. Not supporting empty arrays is a blunder on MicroSoft's part.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1140411)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have `TAKE()` available to me and so cannot definitively state "This is your problem." I'll address two aspects, that of your `MONTHS` Named Range likely being scoped to the WORKBOOK but needing to be scoped to the SHEET so it can specify a particular cell on each different sheet, and of `TAKE()` possibly being the issue due to two potential problems, that of having `,,` specifying the rows parameter and of the first thing addressed below, of `MONTHS` sometimes returning "0" so telling `TAKE()` to return no columns, so an empty array.

The fact that you mention this issue in the situation of working on other sheets, then returning tends toward the first category, the scope of `MONTHS` and so `CELL()` not specifying any particular cell. But the fact that specifying `0` columns seemingly likely to generate an empty array and you being told empty arrays are not supported suggests that being the issue. However, it should not resolve so simply in that case. "Should not" of course not being equivalent to "will not." So the gray area.

But the below will give you three big things to easily check, and to make it easier, I have tested the Named Range scope material and it is so. (I have also tested the standard way of coercing Excel to never return the error described and it does not solve things.) How it might affect `TAKE()` though, I'm not able to say from testing. You'll see how to easily test those two things though. My bet is on the scope of `MONTHS` best fitting the problems described. So it comes first:

Your formula has three possible results, one of which is `0`.

So far, so good. However, in your `TAKE()` function, you use its results to specify how many columns to take to send to the `AVERAGE()` function.

But in forming the array when the `MONTHS` formula returns `0`, you are telling `TAKE()` to take `0` columns in the row it is in. `0` columns means an empty array.

For this to work for you, you need a more complex approach. For instance:

*Use an `IF()` to test `MONTHS`'s result. If `0`, then return a result of $0.00 in cell O5. If it is not the `0` result then use the `AVERAGE()` formula as is.*

Or

*Return a `1` instead of a `0` when the `year` calculated is in the future. One would think all the row on that sheet would be empty, so you'd be taking an average of one cell with a zero value and return zero. If not, some similar logic that would apply might be discernible.*

Another thought, not directly related, and not causing any problem at the moment, would be that writing `CELL("filename")` as you do forces Excel to recalculate every instance of its use on ALL sheets, not just this one, every time Excel recalculates.  And coming from working on another sheet has the problem that is described by part of what you give in the question:  When on the other sheet, and Excel recalcs one of the other sheets, it uses the sheet you are on to give a return for `CELL()` and not the sheet it is being used on, except for the one you are on. So all the others get unfortunate results and Excel seems to realize that and return an error on all of them. As I mention below, this is only aggravating to you, or embarrassing if a boss is complaining about it, if the sheets are dead ends, their results not precedent cells for other sheets, like summation over the years sheets. But if they are, they are feeding an error into those forward uses causing them to return errors...

So, about that:  This causes a problem, not when editing the current sheet, but when navigating to do basically any edit on a different sheet. When you do, the other worksheets will give a `#VALUE!` error to their cells that use `MONTHS`. Arguably not so much a problem, so long as each sheet is self-contained and does not feed into any further sheets. You would go to the sheet to do some work and be aggravated to see the error's effect (surely an "empty array" situation, though I do not have `TAKE()` and so cannot test for the exact effect... it could be it would return an array of errors to take the average on and so `AVERAGE()` would not yield the `#CALC!` error but rather its own `#VALUE!` error. In any case, it'd just be aggravating to you, and disturbing to bosses, but on your first entry on the sheet, it would resolve.

You can fix that problem by creating a `MONTHS` with SHEET scope rather than WORKBOOK scope. And by specifying a cell (any cell, but why not cell A1?) for each of the two `CELL()` functions in it. Once you do this, that problem goes away.

Granted, it means establishing the Named Range for each existing sheet, but if one has a template, or adds new years by copying a current sheet and removing data, the Named Range, with SHEET scope, will be created each time it is copied and renamed. So not a problem for the future. And delete the WORKBOOK scoped `MONTHS` Named Range after doing so.

If `TAKE()` being given the `,,` so no `rows` parameter and sometimes being given a `0` for the columns parameter is not the source of difficulty (I do not give that much chance, but it could be MS changed their whole philosophical approach there:  they don't seem to do what they did with `INDEX()` anymore), then likely the `CELLS()` usage is the issue.

As far as it goes, as all I can presently find about the function is just their advertising pap regurgitated, or nicely regurgitated via pleasant examples, text and video, but with NO ONE looking into real-life usage problems, I am not speaking from having tested it for your use. I am noting MS's approach the last few years has been to not allow the old `,,)` `INDEX()` can use, but rather, when they say the rows parameter is required, they don't even mean their old, "either rows or columns must be specified" but rather that regardless of whether you will provide a columns parameter, you MUST provide a rows parameter. Also, in hoping they are interpreting your `,,MONTHS)` as meaning "THAT row, this many columns" one is hoping they are doing implicit intersection which might really not be so as they have been POINTEDLY getting away from it, in practice and as a concept.

So the problems look like:

1. Needing to use SHEET scoped `MONTHS` Named Ranges versus the (presumably) WORKBOOK scoped version.
2. `TAKE()` being the issue not handling the "0" returned sometimes by `MONTHS`.
3. `TAKE()` being the issue not handling the absence of a rows parameter.
4. `TAKE()` being the issue in BOTH 2 and 3 above being problems.

**Edit:** After all that research and finding nothing helpful, I posted this and then clicked for one more search page... and found a website that has an example using the `,,MONTHS)` part I mention often above and shows `TAKE()` succeeding as it takes the approach of ignoring anything about rows and so returning all rows, like simple uses of parameters in `INDEX()` would.

So THAT aspect is not an issue. Sorry, I've edited the basic answer too much to remove that part where it sits without finally completely rewriting it and it's too late for that now as my bed calls. But that usage is NOT the issue as his example shows a proper return for that usage. It is at:

https://www.get-digital-help.com/how-to-use-the-take-function/

Part 4. in the layout, approximately 20-25% of the way down the page.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).